# Как проверить версию своей программы средствами PHP

Tags: php

Перед загрузкой обновлений моей программы на сервер, система проверяет версию, которая загружена на сервере. Это все происходит банальным:

```
if ('7.12.11' < '7.12.2') echo 'no';
else echo 'yes';
```

Но только проблема в том, что PHP воспринимает '7.12.11' меньше чем '7.12.2', но '11' ведь больше '2'.
Есть ли стандартная функция PHP, которая может делать подобные проверки? Не хочется придумывать велосипед. Спасибо заранее

Comment: Логично. Вы сравниваете две строки (а не числа) посимвольно. И код `единицы` меньше кода `двойки`. Никаких `11 < 2` ту нет.

Comment: та я это и сам понимаю, но может подскажите решение?

Comment: один из вариантов 11 > 02, т.е. передавать '7.12.02'

Comment: или разбить строку на части с разделителем '.' и сравнить каждую часть. Но при этом нужно, что бы версия имела всегда три части.

Comment: Вот вы уже сами предложили два варианта. Выберите один из них и реализуйте.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте функцию [version_compare()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.version-compare.php)

```
<?php
var_dump(version_compare('7.12.11', '7.12.2'));  // int(1)
var_dump(version_compare('7.12.11', '7.12.11')); // int(0)
var_dump(version_compare('7.12.11', '7.12.12')); // int(-1)
```

Comment: я знал что всемогущий PHP имеет нужную функцию. Спасибо большое, что подсказали.